# How can I encrypt a file with the Serpent encryption algorithm?

Tags: encryption

I would like to encrypt a file using a symmetric key algorithm.  AES is a common algorithm, but I don't quite trust it, and I heard that Serpent is a very strong alternative.  How can I encrypt/decrypt a file with Serpent, preferably through a command line?

Comment: Using `gpg` with algorithm like Blowfish may be much easier. See here: http://fooninja.net/2010/09/12/encrypting-and-decrypting-files-with-a-password/ Unfortunately, `gpg` doesn't support Serpent.

Comment: There's no real reason to trust Serpent over Rinjdael (a. k. a. AES). The latter is far better studied than the former which makes the latter less likely than the former to have a serious vulnerability. If you believe that a potential attacker found or can find a useful vulnerability of Rijndael but not of Serpent you should reconsider your threat scenario and maybe present it over on [Security.SE].

Answer (score 0):

if you are really concerned about the security of your computer's files and directories then you should try encrypting with triple encryption algorithm AES-Twofish-Serpent.

There is a great tutorial detailing the steps needed to encrypt both individual files and also directories. It is too detailed to post here and also I do not have permission to copy the content.

The steps outlined by the blogger on his post seem to suggest that it is better. Follow  this [link](http://zefr.wordpress.com/2013/08/27/create-encrypted-file-container-using-truecrypt-ubuntu/) to see the steps he outlined. Hopefully this helps you with your situation.

Comment: Unfortunately, TrueCrypt is no longer maintained, and your answer is obsolete.  Additionally, I don't think that TrueCrypt could even encrypt single files in the first place; I was under the impression that it could only do encrypted volumes.